# Blazor: Optionally providing a method as Parameter

Tags: blazor

I have pagination (One Blazor component) which uses a "Previous" and a "Next" button. This pagination is in a generic form and when I am at the first page I don't want to show the "Previous" button, and when I am on the last page I do not want to show the "Next" button.

My current solution works this way, the way the html is constructed is not important:

```
<some html>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnNext { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowNext { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnPrevious { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowPrevious { get; set; }
}
```

In my html I will check if it needs to be shown (use the booleans) and if so it will be rendered.

Rather than providing an extra boolean Parameter per button I would rather implement it like this:

```
<some html>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnNext { get; set; }
    private bool ShowNext => OnNext.HasDelegate;
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnPrevious { get; set; }
    private bool ShowPrevious => OnPrevious.HasDelegate;
}
```

*Note since Previous and Next are the same I will only use Next in the rest of my code examples*

The value ShowNext would be false in either of 2 cases;

1. you leave out the OnNext parameter in the call; like this: `<Pagination />`
2. Or since an EventCallback can not be null you provide the default value; like this: `<Pagination OnNext="default(EventCallback)" />`

Option 1 can be cone by putting if-statements in my razor file rendering a Pagination component either with or without the OnNext parameter. But I rather make just 1 Pagination component that will provide a method or a default EventCallback, depending on the situation; like this:

`<Pagination OnNext="@(ShowNextButton ? MyNextMethod : default(EventCallback))"`

However this is not allowed since a Method is not of the same type as an EventCallback.

Now I do know that under KISS you just add the 2 extra parameters (in my current solution; see the first code example); it is way simpler for anyone to understand. But that is mainly because the answer to my question is not easy, if at all possible. Otherwise optionally defining the value of a parameter is standard design pattern I often use.

So does anyone know if I can optionally provide a method or a default EventCallback as a Parameter.

Comment: Would changing it to Action be an option for you?

Comment: Would this work `<Pagination OnNext="@(ShowNextButton ? () => MyNextMethod() : default(EventCallback))"` ?

Comment: @Vencovsky I did try that before; then the message is: 

Error CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'EventCallback'

Comment: @PeterMorris You are right! default(Action) is also a valid EventCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to PeterMorris; this is the correct answer:

```
<Pagination OnNext="@(ShowNextButton ? MyNextMethod : default(Action))"
```

default(Action) is of the same type as the method I provided and it is also an EventCallback with no Delegate!

Comment: I meant to make the parameter type an Action

Comment: Yes it was that before, but I thought it was cleaner to work with EventCallbacks. And well you still gave me the insights to come up with a solution. Credits go to you :)